# Asymptotes of hyperbola by considering x tends to infinity

Tags: conic-sections

I saw this derivation of equations of the asymptotes of hyperbola and it goes like this...

For a standard hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, rearranging the terms we get

$y=\pm\frac{b}{a}x\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}$

So as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac{a^2}{x^2}\rightarrow 0$ and hence $y\rightarrow\pm\frac{b}{a}x$.

Therefore the equations of the asymptotes are $y=\pm\frac{b}{a}x$.

I am not very sure if this derivation is correct. Would appreciate if you can share your opinion. Like if there is any step above that is not true in general.

Comment: I have seen many different version of proofs for the asymptotes and they are much more complex than this. It seems to me that something is not quite right here

Comment: Wait a minute ,why only limit the x in the square root to infinity but not including the x outside the square root?

Answer (score 5):

Your derivation can be made correct by changing the final step. Consider your hyperbola:
$$
y=\pm{b\over a}x\sqrt{1-{a^2\over x^2}}
$$
and consider the couple of lines:
$$
y=\pm{b\over a}x.
$$
For a given $x$, the difference $\Delta y=y_{line}-y_{hyperbola}$ (of course you must subtract expressions with the same sign) is then
$$
\Delta y=\pm{b\over a}x\left(1-\sqrt{1-{a^2\over x^2}}\right),
$$
and you can check that 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\Delta y=0.$$

Comment: (+1) This is the only valid proof out of the current answers.

Comment: but we have a product of an expression that tends to infinity times another expression that tends to zero...is the product zero?

Comment: Just multiply and divide by $(1+\sqrt{1-a^2/x^2})$... I thought you were familiar with [this kind of limits](https://www.mathportal.org/calculus/limits/the-limit-of-a-irrationa-functions.php).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right to be suspicious of this method.
Let's apply it to the hypberbola given by the equation

$$ \frac{x^2}{2^2} + x -\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1 .$$

Solving for $y$ as in the method in the question, we get

$$ y = \pm x \sqrt{1 + \frac 4x - \frac 4{x^2}},$$

and as $x\to\infty,$ we find that $\sqrt{1 + \frac 4x - \frac 4{x^2}}\to 1,$
so this method derives the asymptotes $y = x$ and $y = -x.$
But the actual asymptotes are $y = 2 + x$ and $y = 2-x.$

The pitfall in this method can be seen by applying it to any straight line.
For the equation $y = mx + b,$ We factor $x$ out of the right side to obtain

$$ y = x \left(m + \frac bx\right), $$

and then $\left(m + \frac bx\right)\to m$ as $x\to\infty,$
so the method yields $y = mx.$

What the method is actually finding is the directions from the origin to the points at infinity on the curve, which gives the slopes of the asymptotes but not the $x$- or $y$-intercepts.
It will coincidentally give the correct result when the asymptote happens to pass through the origin, as we can predict will happen with
$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ due to symmetry,
but that's an extra fact that has to be shown and it works only in that special case.

However, the method *does* find the slope of each asymptote.
We can then find the $y$-intercept by taking the difference between the curve and a line through the origin with the same slope as the asymptote.
Taking the hyperbola $ \frac{x^2}{2^2} + x -\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1$ again,
taking the solution $y = \sqrt{x^2 + 4x -4}$ and
comparing it with the line $y = x,$
we find that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} (y_\mathrm{\,hyperbola} - y_\mathrm{\,line})
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 4x -4} - x = 2.$$

Hence the difference between the curve $y = \sqrt{x^2 + 4x -4}$ 
and the line $y = 2 + x$ as $x\to\infty$ is zero.
This correctly predicts that $y = 2 + x$ is an asymptote.

[Aretino's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3329793) shows how this method is correctly applied to the hyperbola in the question.

Comment: I think your explanation of all points of view is thorough, and with understanding. We don't know the context from which OP lifted the derivation, but perhaps they were considering only hyperbolas centred at the origin in standard position, to which the method quoted happens to apply, as explained. Of course, the more rigorous way would be to proceed by considering differences in ordinates at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{y}{\pm \frac{bx}{a}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}},$$ and $\text{RHS}\to 1$ as $x\to\pm\infty.$ It then follows that $\text{LHS}$ is also $1$ at infinity. Thus, $$\frac{y}{\pm \frac{bx}{a}}\to 1,$$ which says that $y$ is asymptotic to the lines.

Comment: so do you mean like RHS tends to a fixed constant 1 but LHS does not? I think the problem here for the LHS is that as x increases y increases as well. But does that tends to 1 also? just like RHS? hmmm

Comment: @LanaDR It's an equation. Thus if one side has a value at infinity, so does the other side. They're just expressing the same quantity after all. I'll edit to make this clear.

Comment: @PeterForeman Hm, thanks. It would seem the ratio definition is stronger then?

Comment: @Allawonder No, the difference definition is stronger. You need to prove that this difference is zero in order to find an asymptote. You haven't done that currently.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to the method described in the question. It gives you asymptotic limits of $y/x,$ which is not enough to say exactly what lines are asymptotes.

Comment: @DavidK This was why I did this instead of the difference; it seems (sufficiently or insufficiently) that this is what the author of the derivation cited by OP was thinking about most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my teacher did.
Solve the line $y=mx+c$ with the hyperbola by substitution. The resultant can be thought of as a quadratic in $x$. 
Since the line is an asymptote, it seemingly touches the hyperbola at infinity. The quadratic is:
$$(b^2-a^2m^2)x^2 - 2a^2mcx -a^2c^2 - a^2b^2=0$$ 
Which has $\infty$ as both it's roots. Hence, the coefficient of both $x^2$ and $x$ should be zero, while constant term shouldn't. We get $3$ conditions as follows.
$m=\pm \frac{a}{b}, 2a^2mc=0$(of which neither $a^2$ nor $m$ can be zero, leading to $c=0$), and $a^2b^2$ is not zero(as $c=0$)
This leads to the equation of the asymptotes being $y=\pm \frac{a}{b} x$

Edit: This is to answer Allawonder's doubt.
Assume that $\infty$ is a double root of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Then $0$ ought be a double root of the quadratic $cx^2+bx+a=0$(via transformation of equation). Hence, both $b$ and $a$ ought to be $0$ but $c$ can't be.
P.S. Some people may have a hard time accepting this(I did too) but I got no choice except to trust my teacher.

Comment: but if the coefficients are zero and c is zero, then for the equation we have $a^2b^2=0$?

Comment: The coefficients of $x^2$ and $x$ in the quadratic are zero while the constant term in the quadratic is non zero. These give us three conditions and lead us yo the equations if the asymptotes.

Comment: This is an interesting formal manipulation but I don't think it constitutes a proof. It would be useful to actually prove that it gives a correct answer.

Comment: @DavidK I'm in Grade 11 currently and my teacher gave us this as a proof as we haven't been taught calculus yet. And the other answers seem calculus based.

Comment: The only calculus anyone here is using is limits (also used in the question itself). It may be that the proof of your method also requires limits but your teacher didn’t tell you that part because it would seem too advanced.

Comment: You say, *Hence, the coefficients of both $x^$ and $x$ should be zero, while the constant term shouldn't...* Why does this follow from the fact that the solutions to the quadratic are infinite? I would have thought that both the sum and product of the roots should be infinite too, no?

Comment: @Allawonder, I thought the same. Hence, I shall add to my answer to resolve that part.

Comment: If the original equation is $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 0$ -- an equation of a pair of lines -- then all three coefficients of the transformed equation will be zero. But that's because the difference between the curve and the asymptote is zero not just at infinity but at every other point as well.

Comment: The problem with "Assume that $\infty$ is a double root of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$" is that $\infty$ _cannot_ be a double root of any real quadratic. A lot of "fake proofs" start by making assumptions that look like this. But unlike the method in the question, this one gives correct answers for all non-vertical asymptotes of hyperbolas as far as I can tell, even if the asymptote does not pass through the origin. So there must be a rigorous justification somewhere.